# Apple's recommendation on browser sniffing

Tags: css, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Does Apple have any recommendation for using any technique for browser sniffing (e.g. to distinguish between desktop IE/ FF / Mobile Safari (i.e. iPad)) / Other tablets

I know Apple wants us to avoid using User-agent for the same.

Is the media technique foolproof way to differentiate between iPad and say Xoom?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css">
```

Comment: After reading Akamike's answer I'm now wondering why do you want to do this? Is it because you want your site to work well or is it because you want to track the devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to detect device/user-agent, you want to focus on checking the capabilities of the browser. This includes screen resolution, JS support, CSS support, and more.

Media queries is only one of many techniques you can employ to make your website work well across many devices. To get you started, here are a few helpful resources:

- [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) - A JS library that detects browser capabilities and adds handy CSS classes and JS methods to check this
- ["Mobifying" your HTML5 site - HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/mobile/mobifying.html) - An article on various techniques
- [Yiibu](http://yiibu.com/) - a proof of concept, progressively enhanced site
- [Using media queries in the real world - Broken Links](http://www.broken-links.com/2011/02/21/using-media-queries-in-the-real-world/) - An article promoting starting with a barebones stylesheet and then using media queries to add extra styles on top

Comment: Instead of using third-party library, is there a simpler way of doing this..Like you say JS support..can we detect between iPad and desktop browser, by any specific JS feature..I am trying to avoid any third-party library on my pages..

Comment: Like I said, detect features not user agent. Modernizr (actively maintained) saves you adding all the detection yourself, but if you are interested you can see examples of HTML5 feature detection at http://diveintohtml5.org/detect.html and view the source of Modernizr at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js

Comment: ok..When you say feature detection, will it distinguish between say desktop Safari and Mobile Safari..I mean let's say I want to set width of a div to 100px for desktop Safari and 50px for Mobile Safari..Using feature detection, will I be able to apply the different styles ?

Comment: To do that you would use media queries to say "any device with a device width of X uses this style". That way you will catch Mobile Safari and anything else that has a similar screen. However, as some of the resource I linked to demonstrate, it is better to work in the opposite direction by making a very basic stylesheet first then adding extra styles with a media query that checks for a larger screens.

Comment: There are still some things you might need to browser-sniff for, such as HTML5 autoplay video.

Answer (score 0):

See [Optimizing Web Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW1) on the Apple developer network. This article includes using conditional css to identify browser capabilities, and the differences in various user-agent strings sent by Safari browsers.