# Check the browser with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var user = navigator.userAgent;
var browser = {};
browser.opera = user.indexOf("Opera") > -1 && typeof window.opera == "object";
browser.khtml = (user.indexOf("KHTML") > -1 || user.indexOf("AppleWebKit") > -1 || user.indexOf("Konqueror") > -1) && !browser.opera;
browser.ie = user.indexOf("MSIE") > -1 && !browser.opera;
browser.gecko = user.indexOf("Gecko") > -1 && !browser.khtml;
if ( browser.ie ) {
    var ie_reg = /MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/;
    ie_reg.test(user);
    var v = parseFloat(RegExp["$1"]);
    browser.ie55 = v <= 5.5;
    browser.ie6  = v <= 6;
}
```

Recently, I am leaning JavaScript. I saw some code to check the browser, but I can't follow it well. The code is too hard for me. Can explain it to me? Many thanks.

Comment: Not exactly the way to ask on stack overflow... you need to ask specific questions.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but: It's rarely appropriate to check which browser the user is using. Instead, code should check for the *features* that it requires. This is called "feature detection" rather than "browser detection" and represents the current best practice for writing JavaScript for the web. [Here's a great set](http://kangax.github.com/cft/) of feature tests; [here's another good set](http://diveintohtml5.org/detect.html) aimed specifically at HTML5 stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`navigator.userAgent` contains a String with data about the current browser.

In the second line of code you create a `browser` object which is empty. Then, you add properties which are either `true` or `false` depending on the browser. For example, if the browser is Opera, the word `Opera` is somewhere in `navigator.userAgent`. The same appearently is done for KHTML and Gecko.

To actually check whether a String contains some characters/words, you can use `indexOf`. This will return the index at which the word starts. If it doesn't appear in the String, it returns -1. So checking for `> -1` means checking whether it contains the word.

When it comes to IE, you can differ between version 5.5 and version 6 by executing a regular expression on `navigator.userAgent`. This is a kind of shape you place on the string to filter out what you need. You check whether the version parsed out is 5.5 or is 6 and store that data appropriately.

So in the end the `browser` object contains values on which browser is being used.

Comment: +1 Proabbly worth explaining the `indexOf` thing, just for completeness.

Comment: Good answer.  It has pointed out that capability detection should be performed in favor of user agent sniffing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733268/apples-recommendation-on-browser-sniffing